# Hash Table using quadratic probing question

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I've attached a screenshot of the question I'm not sure about. Why would the string "Banana" % 13 go to spots 8 and 9?

I didn't really try anything other than mod 13 in each spot and since it's going to just equal itself it could go in any spot.[image]

Comment: What do you know about the operation of the algorithm when hashes collide and quadratic probing is used?  Apply that knowledge to the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The question as stated in the image is incomplete. Inspection of the expected answers suggests it assumes the quadratic function used is i^2. However [quadratic probing may use an arbitrary quadratic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing).

Comment: @Jordan Uhrmann  `"Banana" % 13` is not valid C code.  Post the code used.  A [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information you need to use is that quadratic probing is used to resolve hash collisions.

Assuming quadratic probing in your lecture is defined as follows:

```
i := Number of attempts (with 0 being the first attempt)
s := string you need to insert
Position(s, i) = (hash(s) + i²) mod 13 // Maps a string and a number of attempts to a position within the hash table
```

You can systematically exclude hash value as impossible hash values, because there are only two possibilities:

1. The position you want to place it is not occupied: this would mean you could place *banana* there. But, as already explained in the question, banana did end up in spot 12, so in any other position than 12 this could not possibly have been the case, otherwise *banana* would be placed at that position, not at position 12. => this **rules out 1, 4, 7 and 11** to be possible hash values of *banana*
2. The position you want to place it is already occupied: in that case you would use quadratic probing to find the next suitable position, where you have again those two possibilities: occupied or not occupied. Now it's just a matter of systematically excluding impossible positions:

I am starting from the front:

- Position 0: Is occupied by another word than *banana* => there must have been a collision if the hash value of *banana* was 0 => we then would try position `(0 + 1²) mod 13 = 1`. This position is not occupied, meaning *banana* would have been placed there if the hash value was 0. It isn't, so we can **rule out 0**. You can apply the same logic to possible hash values **3, 6 and 10 which rules them out** as well.
- Position 2: Is occupied by another word than *banana* => there must have been a collision if the hash value of *banana* was  => we then would try position `(2 + 1²) mod 13 = 3`. This position is also occupied. => we try `(2 + 2²) mod 13 = 6`. 6 is also occupied. => we try `(2 + 3²) mod 13 = 11`. This position is not occupied, meaning *banana* would have been placed there if the hash value was 2. It isn't, so we can **rule out 2**.
- Position 5: Is occupied by another word than *banana* => there must have been a collision if the hash value of *banana* was 5 => we then would try position `(5 + 1²) mod 13 = 6`. This position is also occupied. => we try `(5 + 2²) mod 13 = 9`. 9 is also occupied. => we try `(5 + 3²) mod 13 = 1`. This position is not occupied, meaning *banana* would have been placed there if the hash value was 5. It isn't, so we can **rule out 5**.
- Position 8: Is occupied by another word than *banana* => there must have been a collision if the hash value of *banana* was 8 => we then would try position `(8 + 1²) mod 13 = 9`. This position is also occupied. => we try `(8 + 2²) mod 13 = 12`. 12 is also occupied, but by the word *banana*. => *banana* could have had a hash value of 8
- Position 9: Is occupied by another word than *banana* => there must have been a collision if the hash value of *banana* was 9 => we then would try position `(9 + 1²) mod 13 = 10`. This position is also occupied. => we try `(9 + 2²) mod 13 = 0`. 0 is also occupied. => we try `(9 + 3²) mod 13 = 5`. 5 is also occupied. => we try `(9 + 4²) mod 13 = 12`. 12 is also occupied, but by the word *banana*. => *banana* could have had a hash value of 9
- Position 12: Trivial and already tackled in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's why I stated my assumption in the answer. And it lines up with the result (which could of course, theoretically, be by accident). But as from my experience that's how quadratic probing is introduced in lectures and this looks like an exam where there is probably a time limit assigned to the task I am 99.99% certain that this is the easy to compute (i. e. by hand) quadratic function used. If not, then, nevertheless, the basic idea still remains valid and will work.